# Header formatting edit

Tags: discussion, editing

I every so often stumble upon an oldish challenge and find myself compelled to edit a lot of answers in order to make them follow the standard/new [header formatting](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/consensus-for-formatting-of-language-and-score-line) (## language name, bytes count).

However as I have not 1000 rep yet, all my edits are going through the review queue and so i fear i'm cluttering it for essentialy nothing.

Should I continue my edits, or should I let someone with enough rep stumble upon it and "correct" the header without having to go through review?

Comment: Off-topic: Is it `## language name` or `# language name`. I've seen people use both so I'm not sure which to use. I suspect that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I personally use `# Python`, for example, but if a language has a long name, or a lot of info has to be included in the title of the answer, I use `##`.

Comment: @KodosJohnson According to the linked post, which i think is the only one debatting that, `## language` but that said, the consensus is not very clear

Comment: @KodosJohnson At the time I'm posting this comment, the consensus there is "it's insane to try to constrain the way people submit their answers to this extent".

Comment: For anyone trying to edit posts, if you follow [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/796874) the bumping should be mininised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It's fine

But only if you don't bump many challenges. Note challenges rather than answers, feel free to bulk update all the answers to a challenge as that effectively only bumps one challenge once. It's one thing to have an old challenge near the top but a completely different story when it's dominated by them. This is our policy when doing major tag edits when introducing tags.

We rarely have anything in the review queues and when they do, they get swiftly emptied again. I doubt our system will fall to a halt if there are slightly more items in the Suggested Edits queue. An advantage to doing this is that we keep consistency across the site and that can only be a good thing.

If you do go about this, see if you can improve answers in other ways such as improving any obvious spelling mistakes (though regional spellings don't count) or the grammar.

In conclusion, the answer is the same if you have the editing privilege or not - don't do it in bulk.

Comment: Can we (now that PPCG has become adult) introduce a way to update formatting without bumping the posts?

Comment: That would be a new feature request meta question I'd imagine

Comment: @Titus, no. Bumping changed posts is the only way of detecting vandalism, so that feature request is not going to prosper.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That´s a good point. But we could add another way: an additional review queue.