# Bulk editing code-golf answers to add headers

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Is it considered bad to edit old [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers to add in headers so that the answers can be easily seen by tools using the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/queries) or [data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)?

I can see pros and cons to doing this, and I what is the *correct* thing to do in this case.

**Pros**:

- Allows for easier analysis and searching
- Can bring more answers to questions that didn't get much attention first time round
- Standardises the posts using older header formats

**Cons**:

- Causes edits to old posts
- Can cause old posts to be bumped
- Adds to the `Suggested Edits` queue, taking up time

Also, are the rules different if it had a header from before the [leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet) became common? I try to make sure if I can improve a post then I do that at the same time.

This question is different to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11566/header-formatting-edit) as that one deals with occasional edits, where as this focuses more on bulk modifications.

> I **every so often** stumble upon an oldish challenge and find myself compelled to edit a lot of answers in order to make them follow the standard/new header formatting (## language name, bytes count).

Comment: Are queues hardly ever have more than a few entries, and there's nothing wrong with bumping old posts occasionally to improve quality. I always edit posts with a bad/missing header.

Comment: If you have >=2000 rep your edits will not be queued.

Comment: @user202729 They'll still be bumped (which, I think, is the bigger issue).

Comment: Whenever we have people that want to go back and update posts (for tags, etc), we just ask that they do it in moderation (~3 an hour).

Comment: @jrtapsell Why do you ask on Meta whether those edits should be made, and then start doing them without waiting for an answer?

Comment: @Laikoni, I took [Nathan Merrill](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20198/nathan-merrill)'s and [Pavel](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60042/pavel)'s comments as a working answer (I paused edits when I posted this, and only resumed after Pavel's answer)

Comment: I can also see that a reason for rejecting edits is `This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.`, does `find` include searching via SEDE and data dumps, which the standard header format helps with, or only the main site search?

Comment: @jrtapsell I'm not sure what your current strategy for the edits is, but please stick to answer given in the dupe target question [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11567/56433), especially `only if you don't bump many challenges. Note challenges rather than answers, feel free to bulk update all the answers to a challenge as that effectively only bumps one challenge once.`

Comment: @Laikoni, Ah, I see your point, my old strategy was a SEDE query that found likely missing header answers ([here](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/795612/code-golf-answers-that-wouldnt-show-on-the-leaderboard)), I have modified it to get questions sorted by bad answer count ([here](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/795630/counting-bad-answer-frequency) {it does have false positives though}), although it does look like there are a lot of questions that only have 1 bad answer, any idea how they should be handled?

Comment: If there only is one answer to be edited, it is still fine to bump the question because of this, just leave enough time between those edits.

Comment: ... I don't like seeing old challenges, because some of them seems blatantly off-topic ...

Comment: @Laikoni does my answer below miss any key points?

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussions with [@laikoni](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni) in the comments it seems the following rules should be followed:

- Try to minimise the amount of bumped questions

  - This can be done by using a query like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/795630/) to find the questions with the highest amount of answers with broken headers
- Questions with low amounts of answers that are incorrect should have time left between fixes, to prevent bumping a large number of old questions.