# Is there a new consensus on answer headers?

Tags: discussion, answers, formatting

When answering question before I always used to use the "Heading" option present on the formatting box. This produces the following markdown:

```
## Heading ##
```

However, within the past couple of days my answers have been getting edited to change it to:

```
# Heading
```

Along with a comment usually saying something like "Use this format instead".

As far as I know this was never a problem in the past and my original heading even works for the leader boards some questions include.

Has the consensus on what headings to use changed?

---

My main reason for asking is I've seen a few suggested edits that do this and I'm not sure about whether or not to approve them. And I'd also like to save others the trouble of having to edit my answers.

Comment: There's no real strict format. I'd highly recommend rejecting the edits to with "doesn't improve" or "clearly conflicts with author's intent"

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### The consensus is either `# Heading` or `## Heading`, whichever you prefer.

[*This previous consensus supports `## Heading`*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/consensus-for-formatting-of-language-and-score-line?noredirect=1&lq=1), but now-a-days it's pretty common to use `# Heading`. This answer is an attempt at a new consensus, allowing either format.

If you like the smaller heading better, use that. I'd recommend against the `### Heading`, as it's a bit small (and obviously not just `**bold**`), but that's just my opinion.

Furthermore, suggested edits to do such things should be rejected, unless they add something else. For example, if they add syntax highlighting, or possibly

```
codeblock formatting
```

instead of

`backtick`

But other than that, they should be rejected with either "Clearly conflicts with author's intent." or "Changes are superfluous".

1 last tip: sometimes, if you prefer the `# Heading` style, it's better to use `## Heading` if the title is too long. This is most common on polyglot and advanced scoring challenges, which can have longer headers (or just long language names).

For example, take this header:

## Python, Ruby, Javascript, R, Julia, Octave, Matlab (5 languages), 186 bytes

You can also write it like this, and it doesn't take up two lines:

### Python, Ruby, Javascript, R, Julia, Octave, Matlab (5 languages), 186 bytes

Comment: @programmer5000 if the title is too long to fit on one line with `# Heading`, use `## Heading`.

Comment: That's still two lines on my machine.

Comment: @isaacg well, that might be time for a triple `### Heading` then.

Comment: Still two lines.

Comment: @MDXF Triple heading shouldn't be, unless you're using a 1024x??? ancient monitor.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No, I mean the third example in *this post*. `##Python, Ruby, Javascript, R, Julia, Octave, Matlab (5 languages), 186 bytes` still takes up two lines on my screen.

Comment: The H2 example at the end is still two lines for me (probably because I'm on a 1440x900 screen :P)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I have the same size, only 1 line for me.

Comment: Probably font differences. It's one line with the graduation userscript.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned answer headers in general as well, use `#Language` or `##Language` like Riker said, but then after that, it is pretty standard to use a format like this, using a comma, strikes, and `bytes`:

```
# Language, <s>127</s> <s>98</s> 95 bytes
```

Like this:

## Python 2, <s>127</s> <s>98</s> 95 bytes

And if your language is supported for prettify markup, you can use `<!-- language: lang-python -->` or something similar for syntax highlighting.